# Why does dart's listSync() behave differently on Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: dart, dart-io

When I walk a directory using the `listSync` function in Windows the entries are sorted but when I run the same code in Ubuntu they are not:

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This (likely) is due to the (non)-Guarantee of the Windows FS.

From [another post](https://superuser.com/questions/523768/cmd-using-dir-to-order-directories-by-name):

> On a FAT filesystem, the entries in any given directory are unsorted, causing the tree-walk to be unsorted. NTFS directories, by contrast, are always sorted

You could always sort your output though:

```
var files = directory.listSync()..sort((a, b) => a.path.compareTo(b.path));
```